# In Django1.11 form, how can I handle url?

Tags: python, django, forms

I have started learning Django a few days ago, I'm not sure how I can handle form url.

myproject/urls.py file as follows.

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^form/', include('app.urls'))
]
```

Here is myproject/app/urls.py file.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.get_name, name = 'get_name'),
    url(r'^/your-name/$', views.your_name, name = 'your_name')
]
```

Here is app/views.py file.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import NameForm

def get_name(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
    else:
        form = NameForm()
    return render(request, 'name.html', {'form' : form})

def your_name(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world.")
```

app/forms.py file.

```
from django import forms

class NameForm(forms.Form):
    your_name = forms.CharField(label='Your name', max_length=100)
```

app/name.html file.

```
<form action="/your-name/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

When I click the submit button, exception occurs.

> The current path, your-name/, didn't match any of these.

When I click the submit button, **http://localhost:8000/your-name/**.
I think it's wrong. I guess **http://localhost:8000/form/your-name/** must appear and *Hello, world* must be printed on the browser.

But it didn't. I wanna know the reason why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure, urls are correct.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.get_name, name = 'get_name'),
    url(r'^your-name/', ProductView.as_view()),
    url(r'^register/$', RegisterFormView.as_view(), name='register'),
]
```

After that call url with app name, it will work surely.

```
<form action="/app_name/your-name/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for contacting me. I have changed <form action = "app_name/your_name">, but **The current path, app/your-name/, didn't match any of these.**exception has occurred.

Comment: do it like /app_name/your_name/

Comment: In project/urls.py file, I import include() function, there is no need to write code as /app_name/your_name/, I guess.

Comment: you changed urls.py in app file?

Comment: I only changed form action.

Comment: change urls.py too,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145285/discussion-between-yuiry-kozlenko-and-sagar).

Comment: Yeah. you're right. I have changed form action url. It works.

Comment: Thanks again Sagar.